# How to covert grey scale image into csv file with x,y and pixel intensity values?

Tags: python, csv, coordinates, pixel, opencsv

I have taken image of hand x-ray which I was able to process to get values of pixel intensity at each point.The output was text with intensity value written at each pixel( somewhat looks like image itself). I want all this data as x,y and intensity value in tabular data( csv file format required for cad purpose).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: We want to extract Z co-ordinate value with pixel intensity and use same for 3d modelling. That is main reason we want all three values in table.(x,y,pixel intensity). We have used this link for pixel intensity- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727793/how-to-convert-a-grayscale-image-into-a-list-of-pixel-values